# How do I achieve this rounded corner shape around icon of a selected bottom nav item with Jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

[image: Bottom navigation design].
This is how my BottomNavigaionItem looks like.

```
 BottomNavigationItem(
                selected = selected,
                onClick = {...}
                icon = {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = if (selected) navItem.iconFilled else navItem.iconOutlined,
                            contentDescription = navItem.route,
                           // modifier = Modifier.background(Color.DarkGray, shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp)).padding(10.dp)
                        )
                },
                label = {...},
                selectedContentColor = MaterialTheme.colors.onPrimary,
                unselectedContentColor = MaterialTheme.colors.onPrimary.copy(0.4f)
            )
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use M3 and the [`NavigationBar`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#NavigationBar(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.WindowInsets,kotlin.Function1)):

```
NavigationBar {
    items.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
        NavigationBarItem(
            icon = { Icon(Icons.Filled.Favorite, contentDescription = item) },
            label = { Text(item) },
            selected = selectedItem == index,
            onClick = { selectedItem = index }
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, I feel terrible not knowing its been on the documentation site the whole time